# Image resize handler visible outside of tinymce editor area if image is bigger than editor in IE

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce 3.5.8 version. In IE8 when i am adding the big images the resize handler comes out of the editor.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. The solution is to set the `unselectable` attribute to images.
I do this on image insertion and editor init:

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('img').attr('unselectable', 'on');
```

Before saving my content to db i remove the attribute.

Comment: @Thariama, I seen that you have answered many tinymce question on stckoverflow, so I wan to ask one thing I am having a problem with re-size handlers, they does not appear where images are. same thing happen with table re-size. please give me a solution

Comment: @Thariama please check my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779780/tinymce-resize-scale-handelers-are-not-in-the-same-place-as-resize-object

Comment: @HowToPlease: i will have a look later