# tinymce - resize/scale handelers are not in the same place as resize object

Tags: tinymce

Tinymce re-size/scale handlers are not appearing in the same place where the re-sizable/scalable object are, but far below the object.

I am using inline feature, this issue is happening with all re-sizable, like table, image etc.

Here is the screenshot of issue:

[image: Tinymce handlers problem]

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution, position of parent of re-sizable object need to be relative

Comment: thnaks, I wan to ask one thing, How can I add custom button format? like I wan to add a format called buttons. Ca I post this question ??

Comment: sure, just describe what you want as exact as possible